# OrientDB functions: unable to save document

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I was following a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MeXLuErdDHw#t=501) when trying to execute the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   var name = prefix + "_" + i;
   var email = name + "@me.com";
   member = {
      "@class": "Member",
      "name": name,
      "password": name,
      "email": email
   };
   var result = gdb.save(member);
}
gdb.commit();
return n;
```

I got error message

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "gdb" is not defined.
(<Unknown source>#15) in <Unknown source> at line number 15 
ReferenceError: "gdb" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#15)
```

Having realised that there is probably no such thing as "implicit variable `gdb`" that the author referred to, I added declaration before the loop as follows

```
var gdb = orient.getDatabase();
```

This time error message said

```
Error on parsing script at position #0: Error on execution of the script Script:
newPOJS ------^ sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: No database
instance found in context (#2) in at line number 2 Wrapped
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: No database
instance found in context (#2) No database instance found in context
```

Quick research pointed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829704/orientdb-no-database-instance-found-in-context-error) and what is apparently an open [bug](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2109). Having applied the suggested workaround, i.e. removing the following block from the config file
        
            
                
                
            
        
I tried again only to get another error

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.save matching JavaScript argument types (object) is ambiguous; candidate methods are: 
class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(java.util.Map)
class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordInternal)
```

Now is there any way to give a hint to the compiler as to which version of the `save` method to use? Or is there, perhaps, a totally different workaround for this problem?

Comment: Using the latest community version, I removed the block from the config file and execute the following without error:`var db = orient.getDatabase();

db.begin();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   var name = prefix + "_" + i;
   var email = name + "@me.com";
   var member = {
      "@class": "Person",
      "name": name
   };
   var result = db.save(member);
}

db.commit();
return n;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you visit our documentation on the topic of functions:

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Functions.html

The referenced video is quite old and as you noticed, the gdb variable is no longer pre-defined. I am working with this section of the documentation to try and make it more robust. We also have some planned improvements for the function portion of our free Studio.

Let us know if you have any additional questions when you've been through the docs.