# OrientDB javascript function, "save" on getDataBase not working

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I'm following this tutorial http://pettergraff.blogspot.fr/2014/01/getting-started-with-orientdb.html

And on the fourth part, we're suppose to create a javascript function which will push some "Members" in the database.

I know this tutorial is old and i've already been through some issues, for instance i had to delete the block

```
<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.handler.OGraphServerHandler">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="50" name="graph.pool.max"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
```

from  orientdb-server-config.xml, to make the following code work :

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();
```

is that normal?

Now that this line is okay, I'm having another trouble, here is "my" code :

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();

db.begin();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var name = prefix + "_" + i;
  var email = name + "@gmail.com";
  var member = {
    "@class": "Member",
    "name": "robin",
    "password": "robin",
    "email": "robin"
  };
  var result = ODocument.save(member);
}
db.commit();

return 0;
```

The problem is now on the "save" method

```
var result = db.save(member);
```

It's saying the method is ambigus, i just don't know what to do :)

Here is the error (in french, i'd like it in english but i didn't find out how to change de language on OrientDB interface)

```
Erroronparsingscriptatposition#0: ErroronexecutionofthescriptScript: createSomeMembers------^sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: LechoixdelaméthodeJavacom.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.savecorrespondantauxtypesd'argumentJavaScript(object)estambigu.Lesméthodesproposéessontlessuivantes???: classcom.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentsave(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord)classcom.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentsave(java.util.Map)(<Unknownsource>#18)in<Unknownsource>atlinenumber18LechoixdelaméthodeJavacom.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.savecorrespondantauxtypesd'argumentJavaScript(object)estambigu.Lesméthodesproposéessontlessuivantes???: classcom.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentsave(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord)classcom.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentsave(java.util.Map)(<Unknownsource>#18)
```

Does someone knows what to do? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something quite equivalent but using Graph API:

```
var db = orient.getGraph();
var member = db.addVertex("class:Member");
member.setProperty("name", "robin");
member.setProperty("password", "robin");
db.commit();

return;
```

Comment: This solution works fine, but i had to add the block I deleted from the config file to make it work !
Do you know why it did not work with getDatabase and save?
Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Charrette. I have never used Document API in Javascript Functions. But it can be an issue ([this one](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3814)) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23848463/4262469) is actually true, I don't know.

Comment: Hi, i've seen this links during my researches, hope we'll know a bit more later ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should convert JSON in a ODocument by calling:

```
var result = new com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument();
result.fromJSON(member);
result.save();
```

Or even:

```
var result = new com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument().fromJSON(member).save();
```

Comment: I didn't succeed at making this solution works, seems like it did not like the member variable i gave him in fromJSON, I don't no why.
But the solution of vitorenesduarte is working, thank you